# Instagram Graph API targeting reels metadata

Tags: python, api

I have been working around **Instagram Graph API** recently and understood how to search across User_name and hashtag, but I want** metadata(insights,metrics,reach)** from **Instagram public Reels** for which I only have **reels link.** I tried finding various methods to get metadata using link but found nothing, even nothing on the documentation too. Can somebody help me out or give any code idea how I can access metadata using just link of the post or reel. I dont even have reel id. Is there any graph API method which can use link to find insights. Please help. If possible can anyone suggest code in Python.

I tried searching across username and hashtag, I am expecting across reels link